# Lower bounds on the bridge number of a knot (and tabulation of bridge numbers)

Tags: reference-request, knot-theory

What methods do we have for finding lower bounds on the bridge number of a knot?

(I'm aware of [this thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/82936/is-there-a-known-method-for-finding-the-minimum-bridge-index-of-a-knot), but the question does not seem exhausted there. For example, how can the Jones polynomial be used to obtain lower bounds? Any developments since 2011?)

One approach is to find lower bounds on the meridional rank, for example by finding presentations of the knot group onto symmetric groups $S_n$. For $n>3$, is there a combinatorial way to check for the existence of such presentation by examining a diagram of the knot, similar to Fox coloring? What other (readily applicable on a diagram) techniques are there for finding lower bounds on meridional rank?

Secondly, I was wondering if there exist databases of bridge numbers of prime knots above 11 crossings. (KnotInfo doesn't give bridge numbers for 12-crossing knots.)

Comment: Another way to get a lower bound on meridional rank is using "KCH" representations: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1112/jtopol/jtu016/abstract;jsessionid=41E98EFE25116E8D76D2A67CCB337E61.f02t03